# Limit rows using Table

Tags: table-field

This is my code I am using, but want to limit it to just one and possibly randomize it also.  Is it possible with Table, I looked at the example on Craft's site but did not see that option.

```
{% for row in block.example %}
    {{ row.examplerow }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38677493/26130

Comment: Brad that is something I tried before but it errors as an unknown filter shuffle.  I did take out the shuffle and tried just slice(0,1) and it worked.  Just need the random part now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never tried it on a table field, but you could try:

```
{% for row in block.example.limit('1').order('RAND()') %}
    {{ row.examplerow }}
{% endfor %}
```

**OK, above will not work**. I went back on my theory and actually tried it on a table field I had laying around. This worked for me:

```
{% set rows = shuffle(block.example) %}

{% for row in rows | slice(0, 1) %}
   {{ row.examplerow }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: If that does work, and returns a single row, you wouldn't need the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for that AbbeyDesign, I tried that and now it returns no records.

Comment: What kind of field is it that you are trying to loop through?

Comment: Trying to loop through a Table field in Matrix.

Comment: @Vin I edited the code above. Let me know if that works. I tried it on a table field I had and it worked for me.

Comment: AbbeyDesign you rock!!! That worked perfect :)